# Displaying only last item in array

Tags: php, mysqli

So i have dropdown menu which i want to fill in with items in array.Problem is that only thing in array is last item in database.
This is PHP:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("79.170.44.77","cl38-baza","3g!cwDwxm","cl38-baza");
//LOADING DATA
if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die("Database Connection Error");
} else {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM People ";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $names= array($row);

        }
    } else {
        echo "no result!";
    }

}
```

And HTML is:

```
                <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                  <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
                  <?php

                    foreach($names as $name) { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $name['name'] ?>"><?php echo $name['name'] ?></option>
                    <?php
                    } ?>

                </select>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: change `$names= array($row);` to `$names[] = $row;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line assigns value to $names

```
$names= array($row);
```

Instead you have to add to array in order to loop in HTML

```
$names[] = $row;
```

Also declare

```
$names = [];
```

above line

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not

```
$names= array($row);
```

You need

```
$names[]= $row;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: To avoid code smells initiate the array with `$names = array();` or `$names = [];` before entering the while.

Comment: Thanks u-nik..I will use that :)

Answer (score 0):

We need to use the code like:

$names = array();

$names[] = $row;

If you want only last item from an array ($names) the use **end($names)**

Answer (score 0):

You are very nearly there!

Change `$names= array($row);`
To     `$names[]= $row;`